# CakePHP session inside Joomla component

Tags: joomla, session-state, cakephp-3.x

I'm writing a Joomla plugin, which is basically just a wrapper around an application written in CakePHP (version 3.3; not in a good position to upgrade this at the current moment). I'm running into various issues with session data.

First problem is that Cake's `Request` object creates a `Session` object, which does not allow for the possibility that the PHP session might already have been started; it throws an error in this case. (I see no changes in this area of the code in Cake v3.6.)

My original solution to this was to have my plugin code close the Joomla session before starting up Cake, and let Cake do its own thing with its own cookie and session table. But by doing this I lose any changes that Joomla might make to its session after my code runs, which isn't ideal.

Next attempt was to hack the `Session` class slightly (proof of concept; a proper implementation to be made without any core changes if it works) to allow setting the `_started` member to `true` before starting the dispatcher. This works, in that Cake and Joomla data are now saved together in the Joomla session table.

However, Cake's session data includes `Auth.User`, the record of the user currently logged in. That record includes objects of type `Cake\I18n\FrozenDate`. On any page load after this has been written into the session, that class is not yet available (Cake's autoloader hasn't run) when Joomla loads the session. So those fields come in as `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`, which then breaks other things.

My current solution to this is to reload the entire session at this point (`session_reset`), first copying any uncommitted changes Joomla has made to `$_SESSION`, then restoring them after the reset.

In limited testing so far, this seems to be working. But I'm wondering whether I've missed some obvious problem, or obvious easier solution. Any comments, suggestions, or thought-provoking questions much appreciated. :-)

For example, is there some way for me to run Cake's autoloader before Joomla initializes the session, without hacking the Joomla core at all? That could be a simpler solution.

If this turns out well, I'll see what I can do to make the code available.